# How can we represent in Hibernate (HBM) a lazy many-to-one relationship while allowing the same class to be referenced in eager mode?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hbm

I am trying to make some of my many-to-one relationships in my hibernate HBM files lazy. Concretely I have a **DataElement** class that references the **Filter** element in a many-to-one relation, I want to make it lazy while keeping access to **Filter** eager in other parts of the application.

I have tried changing my HBM files and found that the lazy="true" is only available at the class level

**DataElement**'s mapping (*I want the many-to-one with filter to be lazy*)

```
<hibernate-mapping package="project.me" default-lazy="false" auto-import="false">
  <class name="DataElement" table="DATA_ELEMENT">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="ID"/>
    <many-to-one name="filter" class="project.me.Filter" column="FILTER_ID" cascade="all"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**FilterAudit**'s mapping (*I want the many-to-one with filter to be eager*)

```
<hibernate-mapping package="project.me" default-lazy="false" auto-import="false">
  <class name="FilterAudit" table="FILTER_AUDIT">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="ID"/>
    <many-to-one name="filter" class="project.me.Filter" column="FILTER_ID" cascade="all"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Filter**'s mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping package="project.me" default-lazy="false" auto-import="false">
    <class name="Filter" table="FILTERS" lazy="true">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="M_ID"/>
        <property name="type" type="filterType" column="M_FILTER_TYPE"/>
        <many-to-one name="predicate" class="Predicate" column="PRED_ID" unique="true" not-null="true" cascade="all"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

By putting lazy="true" at the **Filter** class's level, I make all the DTOs in the application load **Filter** lazily and I don't want that

Is there a way to specify the lazy load **only for** the relation between **DataElement** and **Filter** while keeping the load between **FilterAudit** and **Filter** eager ?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation: Do not use eager fetching. It results in inconsistency and sometimes weird queries. Furthermore, it is difficult to optimise the performance when you use eager fetching. In the mentioned case, I would create different methods to call the database with some fetch joins or entity graphs.

I do not use HBM (or other XML based mapping). I use annotations why I cannot provide you with an answer with XML mapping ([HBM seems to be outdated anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38939467/10902231)).

My preferred way is using the JPA Criteria API instead of JPQL. Some people say that JPQL is better understandable but I prefer the type-safe Criteria API which is less error prone. I prefer entity graphs because they are easier to use dynamically than fetch joins. Nevertheless, the other options work as well.

At first, I would set up the entity classes appropriate to [Vlad Mihalcea's article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). (I infer a unidirectional relationship.)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DATA_ELEMENT")
public class DataElement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FILTER_ID")
    private Filter filter;

    //Constructors, getters and setters...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof DataElement )) return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((DataElement) o).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 56;
    }
}
```

Similar for `FilterAudit` (also `FetchType.LAZY`)...

And then `Filter` (not that interesting because it is unidirectional).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FILTERS")
public class Filter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "M_ID")
    private Long id;

    // Other attributes omitted...

    //Constructors, getters and setters...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Filter )) return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((Filter) o).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 14;
    }
}
```

Now, the relevant part for initialising the lazy loads (or not) gets realised in this case with the JPA Criteria API and entity graphs.

```
public DataElement findByIdWithFilter(long id) {

    EntityGraph<DatElement> graph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(DataElement.class);
    graph.addAttributeNodes("filter");

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<DatElement> cq = cb.createQuery(DatElement.class);
    Root<DatElement> root = cq.from(DatElement.class);

    cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), id));

    TypedQuery<DatElement> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
    typedQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);

    DatElement response = null;
    try {
        response = typedQuery.getSingleResult();
    }
    catch(NoResultException nre) {}

    return response;
}
```

For retrieving an object of the same class without its relationship, just omit the entity graph.

```
public DataElement findByIdWithoutFilter(long id) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<DatElement> cq = cb.createQuery(DatElement.class);
    Root<DatElement> root = cq.from(DatElement.class);

    cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), id));

    return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
}
```